# When sponsoring a spouse (UK visa), what do the various relationship types mean and how do they affect the application?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, marriage, visa

When making a visa application in the U.K. for a sponsor to invite a foreigner to marry there is a section in the application that asks "What is your relationship to *SPONSOR'S NAME*"? There are three options: 1) Fiancé, 2) Proposed civil partner, 3) Unmarried partner. How do these differ in matters of requirements for the application? Do they offer different outcomes for the visa application? Does one involve a marriage whereas the other not? I found online various sources from solicitor's websites but I want something detailed preferably from an official government's website such as the https://www.legislation.gov.uk/.

Comment: Lying about it makes 100% sure your application and future applications will fail. So the best answer by far is the one that is true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Will take it into consideration. Nonetheless, my intention is not to lie, but to clear things out. From my understanding for the Fiance, you need to marry in the future but in the other, you need to show that you cohabitated instead. These nuances are not explicit to me.

Comment: My oh my, the Brits love their fine distinctions. I agree that it could be puzzling.

Comment: Hehehe, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fiancé is someone you intend to marry in the future, usually the near future but some engagements last many years and some break down.
2. Proposed civil partner is someone you intend to enter into a legal Civil Partnership with. This is a formal registration of your coupleness with the government but it is not marriage. Until 2019, civil unions were restricted to same gender couples but are now open to couples of any gender.
3. Unmarried partner is someone you intend to form a relationship with, usually sexual and monogamous, but which you are not intending to officialise with a marriage or civil union.

[Marriages and civil partnerships in England and Wales](https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships)